# how to convert jQuery Object to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 4 columns with Fixed Header and wanted to add rows dynamically with jQuery.

I used following approach:

```
data.forEach(function(res, i) {     
    var cols = (function() {
        var colp = [];
        [res.a, res.b, res.c, res.d].forEach(function(data){
            colp.splice(colp.length, 0, $("<td/>").text(data));
        });
        return colp;
    })();
    $("<tr/>").html(cols.join("")).appendTo(".cotainer");
});
```

`data` is returned from a service and i am iterating over it with foreach loop. However with this approach I am getting output as:

```
<tr>[Object, Object][Object, Object][Object, Object][Object, Object]</tr>
<tr>[Object, Object][Object, Object][Object, Object][Object, Object]</tr>
.... upto no of results returned.
```

I know one way out of that is `colp.splice(colp.length, 0, "<td>" + data + </td>);`, but do not want to go with this approach.

Comment: The issue is because `res.a`, `res.b` etc are objects themselves, not strings. You need to concatenate a string property of the object, not the object itself. We would need to see the actual `data` value to give you more specific help

Comment: Please specify your data...

Comment: res is a json object and res.a returns something say test name and so on. What more specific data i shall specify, if you need more info

Comment: Provide a data sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skip the 'join("")' step and it works:

```
data.forEach(function(res, i) {     
    var cols = (function() {
        var colp = [];
        [res.a, res.b, res.c, res.d].forEach(function(data){
            colp.splice(colp.length, 0, $("<td/>").text(data));
        });
        return colp;
    })();
    $("<tr/>").html(cols).appendTo(".cotainer");
});
```

I think this way is more clear:

```
data.forEach(function(res) {
    var row = $('<tr>');
    [res.a, res.b, res.c, res.d].forEach(function(data){
      row.append($('<td>').text(data));
    });
    $('.cotainer').append(row);
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/m8gdc9ks/1/

Comment: This approach i am aware of. How about my approach and rectifying that

Comment: I'm trying to follow the same method he use ^^, anyway the reason he got [Object, Object] it's because he try to join HTML objects (after wrapping them $("<td/>").text(data)) and not because it is not a text.

Answer (score 0):

keep your required in the returnColumnName, which is there in your data object

```
data.forEach(function(res, i) {     
var cols = (function() {
    var colp = [];
    [res.a, res.b, res.c, res.d].forEach(function(data){
        colp.splice(colp.length, 0, $("<td/>").text(data.returnColumnName));
    });
    return colp;
})();
$("<tr/>").html(cols.join("")).appendTo(".cotainer");
```

});

Comment: Wrong way. Why should i specify column name? If that is the case then why shall i even iterate over those 4 results. I think you understood requirement wrong